# JsonSerializer exception with Facebook C# SDK

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm getting the error:

> "The type initializer for `'Facebook.JsonSerializer'` threw an exception."

with a more specific error of:

> "Could not load file or assembly `'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'` or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find 
>   the file specified"

Comment: You might get more responses if you give more information about what you tried that resulted in that error. Simply pasting in an error message usually doesn't inspire people to look into your problem.

Comment: Adding to the repository to help others... Not expecting a long chain of comments :)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found the issue, so here goes for anyone having the problem:

You need the Newtonsoft JSON library, which you can download from:

http://json.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx

I used the **Newtonsoft.Json.dll** in the **Net** directory.

I actually knew this answer before posting the question, but I figure the answer will help others running into the same issue. Looking into the InnerException of my original exception answered my question :)